# AWS Multicontainer Docker using PHP and NGinx to install Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run Laravel in AWS Multicontainer Docker Environments.

I have followed the tutorial on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html to deploy a simple PHP application with nginx, and it worked. So I have removed all the files in the default `php-app` folder and installed Laravel and ran `composer install` locally, and deployed using `eb deploy` command. However, I received the following error message:

> Warning: require(/var/www/html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17